# Trying to install rails- EISDIR error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to programming and am trying to set up Ruby on Rails using Michael Hartl's tutorial via Terminal on a Mac running Snow Leopard, but I'm a bit stuck on this part. I've tried using rvm 1.9.2, without any luck, and haven't been able to find anything googling. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

```
CZom$ gem install rails -v 3.2.3
/Users/CZom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:253:in `read': Is a directory - /Users/CZom/.gemrc (Errno::EISDIR)
    from /Users/CZom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:253:in `load_file'
    from /Users/CZom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:191:in `initialize'
    from /Users/CZom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `new'
    from /Users/CZom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `do_configuration'
    from /Users/CZom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
    from /Users/CZom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem:25:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/Users/CZom/.gemrc` should be a user specific config file that gets loaded when executing the `gem` command. Sounds like in your case it is a directory instead. Rubygems is complaining therefore.

Try to rename `/Users/CZom/.gemrc` or remove it completely if it isn't needed.

Comment: I removed it completely, and it worked like a charm! thanks so much!