# Rails 4.0 install error in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I have installed Ruby successfully, RVM, rbenv, homebrew, git, and i've tried to install Rails in so many ways (hopefully i didn't mess anything up) but every time i try to do:

gem install rails

I get the following:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:253:in `read': Is a directory - /Users/MARS/.gemrc (Errno::EISDIR)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:253:in `load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:191:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `do_configuration'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

I don't understand what this means and i'm just not sure what else i need to do to get Rails. 4.0.0 installed.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the output of .gemrc, `cat ~/.gemrc`

Comment: see this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709429/trying-to-install-rails-eisdir-error), seems very much like the problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says cleanly: `Is a directory - /Users/MARS/.gemrc (Errno::EISDIR)`, and `.gemrc` file placed in your home folder MUST be a file, not a folder. So either make it a file, or remove folder with such name.